# How to switch between two languages in android app programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I need to switch between two languages inside the android application itself.
Now, I have string values for two different languages in two strings.xml files in two different folders, one is under Values folder(by default) and another one is under values-fr(for french) which is created when tried Edit translation under language in android studio.But I don't know how to switch between the languages.
It shows the default language (i.e., English) but don't know how to implement a way to switch to other language.

Does any one have easy way of implementing it...?

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android-LocalizationActivity](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity)

Here an excerpt from the documentation:

> Keep calm and stay easy with multiple language supported in your
>   android application.
>
> It's basic for android application to be supported multiple languages.
>   Yeah! It's very easy because android has String Resource. Developer
>   just had to prepare the text for different languages then android
>   system will use itself. But frequently problem is "On-time Language
>   Changing". Because the String Resource was designed to be depending on
>   current device language. but if we want to change the language by
>   click some button. It will be difficult to handle it. This problem
>   will solved because I have created a new library to handle application
>   language. It called "Localization Activity" library.

Here the example to use it from the documentation:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.akexorcist.localizationactivity.LocalizationActivity;

public class MainActivity extends LocalizationActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_th).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_en).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btn_en) {
            setLanguage("en");
        } else if (id == R.id.btn_th) {
            setLanguage("th");
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, when user click on a button. It will change to English or Thai language.

Comment: thnx frnd....'ll try

Answer (score 0):

You can use the locale class to do this .Hope this helps

```
   public class LocaleLanguage {

    private static Locale mLocale;

    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        mLocale = locale;
        if(mLocale != null) {
            Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        }
    }

    public static void updateConfig(ContextThemeWrapper wrapper) {
        if(mLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setLocale(mLocale);
            wrapper.applyOverrideConfiguration(configuration);
        }
    }

    public static void updateConfig(Application app, Configuration configuration) {
        if(mLocale != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            //Wrapping the configuration to avoid Activity endless loop
            Configuration config = new Configuration(configuration);
            config.locale = mLocale;
            Resources res = app.getBaseContext().getResources();
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

here is the application class

```
    public class App extends Application {
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        // get user preferred language set locale accordingly new locale(language,country)
        LocaleUtils.setLocale(new Locale("iw"));
        LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this, newConfig);
    }
}
```

here is the your activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public BaseActivity() {
        LocaleUtils.updateConfig(this);
    }
}
```

And for more refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922040/how-to-change-language-for-a-whole-android-application) for whole tutorial refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/)

Comment: thanks mate....'ll try this one

Comment: ok try this.let me know if you have queries.:)

Comment: i found it difficult to toggle....actually i need to develop an app which is in english by default, whenever i press the button in actionbar it toggles between tamil language and english(default)...if u have any way of implementation please share it here....

Comment: I am implementing this in my app follow [link] (http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/) step by step you get your requirements its easy.:)